# Getting "complex-functions.cpp:57:25: error: expected initializer before ‘add’" What does it mean?

Tags: c++, class, typedef, private, complex-numbers

I have a class declared like this in a header file :

```
class COMPLEX{
    private:
    typedef struct{
    double real;
    double imaginary;       
                }complex;
```

Now when I call this from the function driver I get that error "expected initalizer before add  right here in this section of code, and as you can see I have it just like other parts that compile just fine.

```
    //returns the phase of the complex number
double COMPLEX ::  getPhase(complex n, int form)
{
 if(form == 0)
 {
    float x = n.real;
    float y = n.imaginary;
    return(atan2(y,x));
 }
 if(form == 1)
 {
    return(n.imaginary);
 }
}

//adds two complex numbers together
void COMPLEX :: complex add(complex n, complex m, int form)
{
    complex temp, temp2, temp3;
 if(form == 0)
 { 
    temp.real = n.real + m.real;
    temp.imaginary = n.imaginary + m.imaginary;
    return(temp);
 }
 if(form == 1)
 {
    temp3.real = (n.real*cos(n.imaginary) + m.real*cos(m.imaginary));
    temp3.imaginary = (n.real*sin(n.imaginary) + m.real*sin(m.imaginary));
    temp2.real = getMagnitude(temp3, 0);
    temp2.imaginary = getPhase(temp3, 0);
    return(temp2);
 }
}
```

There is just the error right before add, I've tried putting things before the complex function caller but it still said it was expecting something before add.... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
void COMPLEX :: complex add(complex n, complex m, int form)
```

looks like it is returning both `void` and `COMPLEX::complex`.

You have to decide what you want it to return.

Comment: I need it to return the complex function, but when I take void out I get this -->
`complex.h:25:5: error: ‘typedef struct COMPLEX::complex COMPLEX::complex’ is private
complex-functions.cpp:57:24: error: within this context
complex-functions.cpp:57:24: error: ‘complex’ was not declared in this scope
complex-functions.cpp:57:35: error: ‘complex’ was not declared in this scope
complex-functions.cpp:57:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’ `

Comment: I can't tell if `add` is a member function of COMPLEX or if it is a free function. To be usable by non-members, the typedef will have to be public.

Comment: add is a member of the typedef struct complex which is part of the Class COMPLEX which is private, where as the complex add function is defined as public

Comment: `class COMPLEX
{

private:
 typedef struct{
  double real;
  double imaginary;  
   }complex;
public:
  
  double getReal(complex n, int form );
  double getImaginary(complex n, int form);
  double getMagnitude(complex n, int form);
  double getPhase(complex n, int form);
  complex add(complex n, complex m, int form);
  complex subtract(complex n, complex m, int form);
  complex multiply(complex n, complex m, int form);
  complex divide(complex n, complex m, int form);` and so on

Comment: If it is defined outside the classes, it should probably look like `COMPLEX::complex COMPLEX::add(COMPLEX::complex n, COMPLEX::complex m, int form)`. You might want to simplify the nesting of the types...

Comment: OKay, this seems to have cleared it up for the addition part of the code, now that I know whats wrong I can fix up the other functions. 

Yeah, I would really.... REALLY love to do that. Unfortunately for me, I have the worlds worst C++ teacher who gave us code in C and told us to convert it to C++ and we were only allowed to add in classes and convert printf to cout and scanf/getc to cin.... we even had to keep fprintf's .